# Creating a dropdown/select list from csv with d3 nest

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, d3.js, drop-down-menu

I am looking to create a `dropdown/select list` from a `.csv` file. Is it possible to create a `dropdown/select` list from `d3 nest`? I'm working on a force directed graph that is being populated from a `.csv` file. I would like for the user to be able to choose from the dropdown list which node it wants to highlight. Previously I used a text search based and it worked, but I am actually looking for a `dropdown list` instead of text based search. Thank you in advance!

You can refer to [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/rajaiskandar/uf35nvyz/)

```
var nodesmap = d3.nest()
    .key(function (d) { return d.name; })
    .rollup(function (d) { return { "name": d[0].name, "group": d[0].group, "size": d[0].size  }; })
    .map(graph.nodes);    

var output = document.createElement('block_container');
var select = d3.select("#searchName").append("select");

list.selectAll("option")
            .data(nodesmap)
            .enter()
            .append("option")
            .attr("value", function(d) {return d.key;})
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.key; });

return output;
```

I used the `les_mis.csv`

P.s: I am not even sure if I had setup the `jsfiddle` appropriately. Excuse my noobness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you typed `list` when the variable name is `select`.  Second, your `nodesmap` object does not have properties of `.key`.

This will work though:

```
  var select = d3.select("#searchName")
    .append("select")
    .on('change', searchNode); //<-- fire your search function on change

  select.selectAll("option")
    .data(graph.nodes) //<-- use graph.nodes
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", function(d) {return d.name;}) //<-- it has a name property
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name; 
    });

 function searchNode() {

  //find the node
  var selectedVal = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; //<-- get value from dropdown

  ...
```

Full working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jrQKCxAnNLqEo6Z6CCfR?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I will give it a go and let you know any updates. Truly grateful to be getting help on this matter..

Comment: This works brilliantly. Thanks Mark! Your explanation is very good and straight forward. You were spot on using "graph.nodes"  rather than "nodesmap". Initially I was using "graph.nodes" but somehow or rather it didn't work and then I started blast aimlessly due through frustration. I learned something new to with "this.options[this.selectedIndex].value". I've not encountered this before as I actually have left "coding/programming" for about 10 years now. Anyway, really appreciate it!